VS Code Search by folder gone in v1.89?
I updated my VS code like a month or 2 ago and it seems to have removed the search bar when you search by folder/projects. for example, when you have your file tree, you could press ctrl+F and a search bar would show and you could search by folder
folder tree
but now the if you press ctrl+f the search bar only appears on the file side of things and not the folder tree.
search bar in file
I can "search" by pressing ctrl+shift+e and type what I want, but it filters as I type, which is ok but I prefer the search bar as it's more faster for me. Any ideas?
Also, I do have a search bar here but this only searches by open files and not the folder tree
open file search
I've tried looking this up online but can't find anyone else talking about it. The "closest" thing would be that the file explorer section is gone, but that's not related to my issue. The company I work in, all my colleagues are experiencing the same "issue" after they updated to the latest vs code as well.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78422607/836330 - the keybinding has changed.

The keybinding for list.find changed to ctrl/cmd+alt/opt+f in VS Code 1.89 due to user feedback that people wanted ctrl/cmd+f to open the editor find widget even if focus is in the primary sidebar.
See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_89#_find-in-trees-keybinding and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/210634.
Fun fact: I've also mentioned this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78422607/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78422566/11107541. But I don't think it's appropriate to close this question as a duplicate of either.
If you want to change it back, put the following in keybindings.json:
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+f",
    "command": "-list.find",
    "when": "(isLinux || isWindows)",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+f",
    "command": "list.find",
    "when": "(isLinux || isWindows) && listFocus && listSupportsFind",
},
// for macOS users:
{
    "key": "cmd+opt+f",
    "command": "-list.find",
    "when": "(isMac)",
},
{
    "key": "cmd+f",
    "command": "list.find",
    "when": "(isMac) && listFocus && listSupportsFind",
},


Oh damn, Thanks a bunch man. You mentioned Keybinding and I read over your posts as well. Found out how to change it.

@JoshuaGonzalez nice. I've also edited my post to add that.

The keybinding for the folder tree was replaced with:

ctrl + alt + f (Windows, Linux)
cmd + opt + f (Mac)

To change this just go to File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts

After the new page opens up, just search for "list.find" and click the edit icon:

Lastly, just enter your preferred shortcut and hit "enter"

